# Remove product Compare list?

Tags: product, compare

We have enable the Use Flat Catalog Category and  Use Flat Catalog Product. After that site is loading while login to myaccount. We checked this, after login in some category page show product compare list around 300 product. So the page page load time increased. Where to remove the Product Compare list product?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
```

add this code in every `.xml` files under `<reference name="right">`
this will solve your problem.